# When specific string in output, do another command

Tags: monitoring, inotify

I am currently trying to write a script that monitors my bashrc. I use `inotifywait -m /root/.bashrc`. I wanted to use this as a start script, so everytime my machine boots, `inotifywait` is executed and waits until changes in my bashrc are made.

In my case:

The output of `inotifywait -m /root/.bashrc`, when changing stuff in the bashrc is:

```
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
/root/.bashrc OPEN
/root/.bashrc CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE
/root/.bashrc MOVE_SELF
/root/.bashrc ATTRIB
/root/.bashrc DELETE_SELF
```

Is there any possibility (an if-clause, a function, or something else) that when the string "ATTRIB" appears in the output, another command is executed? In this case, sending an email.

I am open to any (better) ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution while searching the internet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371665/bash-script-to-read-a-file-and-run-a-command-based-on-a-specific-string

Based on this post, I was able to write a functional script. It certainly can be done better and prettier, but this works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR_TO_WATCH=/root
STRING=ATTRIB
WATCHED_FILE=".bashrc"
BRC=/root/.bashrc
ORIG_PATH=<origin-path>
DEST_PATH=<dest-path>

cd "$DIR_TO_WATCH" || exit

inotifywait -qme attrib --format '%f' ./ | while read -r WATCHED_FILE; do
    if grep "$STRING" "$WATCHED_FILE" &>/dev/null; then
        if cp "$ORIG_PATH".bashrc "$DEST_PATH"; then
            sleep 1
            rsync "$BRC" "$ORIG_PATH"
            echo "Bashrc was changed."

        else
            echo "There was an error while copying the old bashrc."
        fi
  fi
done
```